# IPS Screen viewing angle - the picture gets less bright when viewing from side

Tags: display, colors, brightness

I have recently bought 23" ASUS VX239H display with AH-IPS A+ screen.
I have read many articles before about wide viewing angles of IPS displays.
When I first looked at it I was surprised, how much the display looks differently from various angles.

[image].

The picture on IPS screen gets significantly darker when not watched from front - more than the older HP L1710.
I guess it has something to do with LED technology used. 
Is it normal for IPS LED displays or is it specific for this monitor?
From the front the picture looks great so I do not suppose it is a fault of this particular display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have misunderstood the "wider viewing angle" benefit of IPS.

The benefit of IPS is more around better color accuracy (i.e. less color shift) at wider viewing angles, rather than maintaining uniform brightness. Two very different things.

Quoting from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPS_panel#Advantages):

> IPS panels display consistent, accurate color from all viewing angles

**EDIT**

The reason why uniform brightness can't be achieved at wide angles is just basic physics. The light is directional! Look at the yellow arrow in the following diagram; clearly you're going to experience maximum brightness right in front of the monitor:

[image: LCD Panel Drawing]

Comment: Perhaps, but even in the advertisment to this monitor there is a picture of the screen viewed from different angles with the same picture. And I have seen youtube video showing the monitor screen from bottom, top, etc.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Lol! Don't believe what they show in ads. As for the YouTube video, that's misleading because of the camera's auto-exposure. I have three different IPS monitors in my house and I have looked at them all at various angles. They all exhibit the same issue you're seeing - they get darker at wider angles and significantly so at anything more than 45 degrees. It's perfectly normal limitation of the technology :-)